# 2 Separate Tab bars in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create 2 separate navigation tab bars in flutter app.

On the top bar I want to add some icons which lead to different pages other than the botton icons. I have tried to add them in a material tab with home as a DefaultTabController which makes all the icons on top and bottom reach the same page according to their order.

To get a better visiual of what I am trying to acheive here is the image below

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'My first app'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.flight)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.flight)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: const TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.rss_feed),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              )
            ],
            labelColor: Colors.yellow,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            indicatorColor: Colors.red,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what I am receiving now:

[image]

I am new to flutter and I am in a practical project to learn so if you can provide some clarification and expalnantion to the answer would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it others widget might be better choice in this case. Try this widget and you can decorate the selected index from `controller.page.toInt()`

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void onTap(int index) {
    controller.animateToPage(index,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.bounceIn);
  }

  final PageController controller = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => onTap(0),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), child: Icon(Icons.flight)),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => onTap(1),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => onTap(2),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => onTap(3),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            ),
          ]),

          //main View
          Expanded(
            child: PageView(
              controller: controller,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          //*
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround, children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => onTap(0),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), child: Icon(Icons.flight)),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => onTap(1),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => onTap(2),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => onTap(3),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            ),
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```